# Populating Android Table

Tags: java, android, xml, tablelayout

I have an ArrayList of Hashmaps that I want to use to populate a table. The problem is that it will only populate the first row and if I try to add a new Row it shifts my table by one column.
I will attach the code here (please ignore the for, for the moment I just want to populate my table with one hashmap)

```
    for(int i = 0;i<clientList.size();i++) {
           // for (int j = 0; j < contact.size(); j++) {
                for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : contact.entrySet() ) {
                   // clientList.get(i).entrySet().toArray();
                    System.out.println(clientList.get(1).entrySet() + "Arrays anyone?");
                    TableRow tr1 = new TableRow(SingleContactActivity.this);
                    tr1.setId(R.id.tableRow+1);
                   // tr = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tableRow+1);

                    label_date = new TextView(SingleContactActivity.this);
                    //  label_date.setId(R.id.data);
                  //  label_date.setId(R.id.data-1);
                    label_date.setText(data);
                    t1.addView(label_date);


                    //  System.out.println(data);

                   // tr.setId(R.id.tableRow);
                   // TableRow tr2 = new TableRow(SingleContactActivity.this);
                   // tr2.setId(R.id.tableRow);
                    label_serialnr = new TextView(SingleContactActivity.this);
                    //label_serialnr.setId(R.id.serialnr);
                    label_serialnr.setText(serialnr);
                    tr_head.addView(label_serialnr);


                    label_conindex = new TextView(SingleContactActivity.this);
                   // label_conindex.setId(R.id.conindex);
                    label_conindex.setText(conindex);
                   // System.out.println(contact.get(conindex)+"Hello");
                   // t1.addView(label_conindex);

                    label_cantitate = new TextView(SingleContactActivity.this);
                    //label_cantitate.setId(R.id.cantitate);
                    label_cantitate.setText(cantitate);
                   // t1.addView(label_cantitate);


                    t1.addView(tr1);
                    //t1.addView(tr_head);

                    // if(count %4==0) {
                    //   tr = new TableRow(SingleContactActivity.this);
                    // tr.setId(R.id.tableRow + count);
                    //  }
                    // tr.addView(label_date);


                    //label_serialnr.setId(R.id.serialnr+1);
                }
           // }
        }
```

and my xml

```
      <TableRow
    android:id = "@+id/tableRow"
    android:layout_width="68dp"
    android:layout_height="334dp"

    >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/data"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="DATA "
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:layout_column="1">
        </TextView>
          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/serialnr"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text=" SERIALNR "
              android:textSize="17dp"
              android:layout_column="2">
          </TextView>

          <TextView
              android:id = "@+id/conindex"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
              android:text = " CONINDEX "
              android:textSize="17dp"
              android:layout_column="3">
              </TextView>
          <TextView
              android:id = "@+id/cantitate"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:text = " CANTITATE "
              android:textSize="17dp"
              android:layout_column="4"
              >
              </TextView>
    </TableRow>
```

sorry as my code is messy, I've been trying a lot of things :(

Comment: you are adding `View` in `TableRow`. `TableRow` always add new View horizontally not vertically thats why you are not able to see the Views

Comment: If I turn the table to a horizontal view will it work?

Comment: probably i didn't tried, may be you can try some thing like this use the `LinearLayout`, keep this `LinearLayout` in `ScrollView` and add the `View` to the `LinearLayout`, Make sure to use Vertical `LinearLayout`